# Haskell image processing library - hip - readImageExact OK, readImage compile error

Tags: haskell, image-processing

I am using the Haskell image processing library hip pulled using stack with the lts-8.23 resolver (iirc). I am a just learning Haskell. In brief: readImageExact works as I expect, but readImage does not.

This Main.hs compiles as expected:

```
import Graphics.Image 
import Graphics.Image.IO 
type BasicImage = (Image VS YCbCr Word8)
main :: IO ()
main = do 
   img  <- readImageExact' JPG "frog.jpg" :: IO(BasicImage)
   return ()
```

The one using only readImage does not:

```
   img  <- readImage' "frog.jpg" :: IO(BasicImage)
```

The error message I get is:

```
• No instance for (Readable (Image VS YCbCr Word8) InputFormat)
    arising from a use of ‘readImage'’
• In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    img <- readImage' "frog.jpg" :: IO (BasicImage)
 [...]
```

Setup: new installation of stack with lts-8.23 resolver, hip pulled from Stackage (1.5.3.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is simply no `Readable` instance for the format `InputFormat`, except [for one](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hip-1.5.3.0/docs/Graphics-Image-IO-Formats.html#t:Readable):

```
instance AllReadable arr cs => Readable (Image arr cs Double) InputFormat
```

The `AllReadable` basically says that we want to be able to read all formats. However, the kicker is `Double`. You cannot use `readImage'` with `Image  * * Word8`, you have to use `Image * * Double`.

I guess this is due to the `HDR` format, which uses `RGB Float`.